# PreparedStatement don't insert Data into MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following Database:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    text MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NAME)
);
```

And I have the following code:

```
public void saveBlocks(Map<String, Block> blocks) throws SQLException{
    String userInsertQuery = "Insert INTO b (name, text) VALUES (?, ?)";
    preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(userInsertQuery);
    int batchCounter = 0;
    for(Block block : blocks.values()){
        preparedStatement.setString(1,block.getId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,block.getText());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        batchCounter++;
        if(batchCounter%200 == 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();

}
```

But it doesn't write anything into the database. 
I have nearly the same code for another table and there it works without a problem. The only difference is the amount of inserts I do (in the working case: over 1million, in the non working case: around 70)

I can't find a solution and I'm out of ideas.

What I tried:
- connect.commit() => since I have autocommit true no change. (or do I use it wrong?)
- I don't have a auto increment on my key so no problem there.

You have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must finally `commit` the transactions with:

```
connect.commit();
```

with `connect.setAutoCommit(false);`

```
String userInsertQuery = "Insert INTO b (name, text) VALUES (?, ?)";
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(userInsertQuery);
connect.setAutoCommit(false);
int batchCounter = 0;
for(Block block : blocks.values()){
    preparedStatement.setString(1,block.getId());
    preparedStatement.setString(2,block.getText());
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
    batchCounter++;
}
int[] results = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
connect.commit();
```

Comment: It didn't work for me... I tried it and yeah in the end I let it slide. I do it now different. I load them into file and read it from there. But thanks.